# Align graphs in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I draw graphs in a Notebook I would like to have them aligned but the graphs will shift more to the right if the values on the y-axis are big since numbers then take more space.

How can I make the graphs (actually the x-axis) to be aligned?

Comment: What are you using to create graphs? matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, I am using matplotlib